# Can I create a SVG site containing files with all these licenses?

Tags: mit, apache-2.0, license, cc-by-sa, cc-by-nd

### My site

My site is like a gallery of SVG files from different sources, with different licenses. In a way similar to https://www.flaticon.com/.

When clicking on an item it will show on a modal together with some info and a link to the correct license.

### Question

Can I create a service like I've described above, with SVG files with the different licenses below?

- https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/
- https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
- https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
- https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
- https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/

### Share Alike

One thing I'm worried about is SA.

It says:

> ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.

From my perspective, I don't remix them. I keep them on the same website, but you download them one by one, not all as a whole. Am I correct or wrong?

### NoDerivatives

> NoDerivatives — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you may not distribute the modified material.

This does sound like I can't build a website around an SVG file with this license. Correct or wrong?

### Summary

Can I place the different SVG files with these licenses on the same site? If not, which licenses will not work and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will be fine. Each of these images will have their own license, however as long as you meet the conditions (i.e. for CC: proper attribution, non-commercial use if -nc, etc.) it's not an issue.

> but you download them one by one, not all as a whole.

<s>If you're providing a separate download (i.e. you are splitting images that were previously distributed together into separate downloads / archives / etc.), you are in fact transforming the content. Just ensure that your 'split' images / downloads contain a copy of the appropriate license (and attribution) and you'll be meeting that condition.</s>

Edit: I'm going to do some more research on the above for you, so take the preceding paragraph with a grain of salt right now!

Edit: As long as you're not changing the content of the images, you're not transforming them or creating a derivative. From the CC website:

> Can I reuse an excerpt of a larger work that is licensed with the NoDerivs restriction?
>
> The NoDerivs licenses (BY-ND and BY-NC-ND) prohibit reusers from creating adaptations. What constitutes an adaptation, otherwise known as a derivative work, varies slightly based on the law of the relevant jurisdiction.
>
> ...
>
> All CC licenses grant the right to reproduce a CC-licensed work for noncommercial purposes (at a minimum).

See [this](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#when-is-my-use-considered-an-adaptation) for further information.

The MIT license is so permissive that I wouldn't worry about it too much - Just include a copy alongside any MIT licensed images.

The Apache license is much the same (AFAIK), but I'm much less familiar with it in general.

You **will** make sure that any downloads (at least, zips that you link) contain the appropriate license - a download counts as distribution. I would argue that if someone downloads the image through alternate means (right-clicking --> Save as, etc.) that the link on the page would cover you. IANAL, but you're not violating the spirit of the agreement at least.